# When I update an Elasticsearch document it ends up in the end of the index

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch, kibana, elk

I'm writing a Kibana plugin and I'm facing some problems: when I try to update a document from a React Datagrid, it ends up in the end of the index, so when the grid is reloaded it is displayed as the last element of the grid (the search is paginated).

It happens for every update (not a Datagrid problem).

I want it to keep its position, how can I achieve that?

Thanks

Comment: May be using a sort will help you to have a consistent way to display results?

Comment: There is no "begin" or "end" in an index and each document doesn't have any defined "position". The index at which a document shows up in the results depends on the sort applied to the your search. Can you shed some light on the query you're making?

Answer (score 0):

A simple sort solved the problems, thank you everyone for the help.